# Bluetooth speaker and buds: Delay in playback, truncates short sounds

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio

Recent android phone.

I initially observed this issue just with Boom and Megaboom bluetooth speakers, but I now have Jabra buds, and see the same issue:

The first 100-500 milliseconds of audio do not play.

This is an issue if it is a language app (that says a word), or a workout app (that says "start" and then 30 seconds later says "stop") because all or most of the sound **does not play** at all.

What is the resolution?

I have been forced to use wired buds for language learning (which is NO fun!)

When I used apple airpods I did NOT have this issue. (I no longer use airpods because they [cannot be repaired](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/neaz3d/airpods-are-a-tragedy) or battery-replaced)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has by Design a too bad Bluetooth Audio latency

I have the same Problem for Years and it never got better. I even have that with my Car Audio

For more Information see this: https://www.soundguys.com/android-bluetooth-latency-22732/

very informative

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think it was this bad with the airpods?

Comment: That's possible. As you can see in the Article, different Devices have different latencies. Maybe they were able to keep the latency below 100ms with your phone.
I have a really bad latency when navigating with my phone through my car audio. To not miss a turn I always keep some music ultra low in the background and the navigation louder. Perhaps you could do something like that too.

Comment: Man, that whole thing is horrible. And how is it you and I seem to be the only ones beefing about it? This has to have a negative impact on hundreds of thousands of people.

Comment: My guess is that the majority of the people don't know what to do about it/where to complain about it or just shrug their shoulders